# What's the opposite of '!important' in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a jQuery plugin that uses CSS styles to add colors and margins to nested DIV tags. Since I'd rather keep the plugin as a single file, my code adds these colors and margins directly as CSS attributes to the DIVs using jQuery's `.css()` method. (The values for these attributes can be customized when the plugin is initialized.)

However, I also wanted to give users the power to style these DIVs using their own stylesheets, so I'm also adding classes to each group of DIVs (for which the names can also be customized). This seemed like the best way to provide the best of both worlds.

The only drawback seems to be that inline `style="..."` attributes (generated by jQuery's `.css()` method) always override class styles set in the external stylesheet. I can, of course, use `!important` styles in the stylesheet, but doing this again and again is cumbersome.

So: what I really want is a way to make the inline styles automatically take a *lower* priority than the external class styles, without having to make the external class styles `!important`.

I have not read about such a thing. Any suggestions? (Or: is there another approach I should be taking to style my DIVs in the plugin?)

Comment: Don't think such a thing exists. But maybe you could use .addClass() instead?

Comment: Is it a option to provide your css separated? I've used some plugins that does this, and found out that those are easier to customize.

Comment: @Andre: Example, please?

Comment: I mean as a separated .css file

Comment: `!unimportant` just means that all your programming is a waste of time :-p

Comment: Man, I really wish there was an !unimportant, because right now it would save me a lot of headache and hard work trying to fix this mess of css we have inherited.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What's the opposite of `!important` in CSS?

There isn't an exact opposite, but there are lower precedence selectors.

[w3c spec defines the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade), might as well read it.

inline styles have highest precedence, and you're after a low-precedence style, you'll need to add CSS via a stylesheet or `style` element.

Because you're using jQuery, adding a custom style element is *very easy*:

```
$('<style type="text/css">.foo {color: #FF0000;}</style>').prependTo('head');
```

The issue you're then going to find is that a user who has specified `.foo` in a stylesheet will need a higher specificity to win out over the `style` element, so I'd recommend using an additional class for each element so that a user can override the defaults:

```
.foo.override { color: #0000FF; }
```

In all cases you're going to want to carefully pick your selectors to have the least specificity possible.

Comment: @zzzBov... looks like we are thinking alike!

Comment: Probably a better solution is for the user's CSS to use an ID, i.e. `#wrapper .foo` so you don't need to add override through jQuery.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, the user could always use `html .foo` instead, but `.foo.override` makes it understandable that you're overriding the default styling. It's important in CSS to use the *lowest* specificity selector possible, adding an `[id]` is overkill.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I'll be using this plugin at least twice on a single page, with different styles possible in each instance. So something like `#id1 .item` will probably be necessary.

Comment: (after actually implementing this) instead of `#id1 .item` I used `.randomclassname .item` and added the randomclassname to `this` at the top of the plugin. Seems to work the way I wanted.

Comment: Well, I have no ideal solution now, but I have a couple of compromises. I guess that'll have to do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12):

In general, if you are considering using `!important`, then there's a good chance you should be thinking about tidying up your stylesheets.

`!important` can be useful to force things to behave, but most of the time it is an indicator of overly-complex CSS.

There isn't an opposite of `!important` (nor even the ability to assign levels of importance), but if there was, the same point would probably apply.

CSS rules are applied in a very strict order of precedence, and if you follow the best practices of how to apply your CSS (ie style element names and class names in preference to IDs and inline styles) then it is usually possible to override things as required without resorting to `!important`.

The only times I've found that I've actually needed `!important` have been where I've been working on a stylesheet which was layered on top of existing styles defined by a CMS template which I didn't have any control over.

**In your case**, you are setting inline styles using jQuery. This is a perfectly good thing to do if you want to achieve spot-effects. However for performing general styling, with the possibility of overriding it, you would be better off if you defined those styles in your CSS, and used jQuery to add or remove the classname in order to apply those styles.

This would enable you to apply the styles to groups of elements but still have overrides for them where required.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

What you might do is `prepend` a new style to the `head` of the page and then call the style in your script.

Something like

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .theStyle{ //WHATEVER} </style>").prepend("head");
```

Then you can use `addClass` in your script

```
$("whatever").addClass("theStyle");
```

Because you are adding it as the first thing in the `head`, other stylesheets should override the styles.

So your users could add a `.theStyle` rule to one of their .css files and it should work.

**EDIT**

*To clarify based on @zzzzBov's comment below*

`style` is an **internal** stylesheet and the .css files I mentioned are **external** stylesheets

The **external** will only take precedence if the specificity is greater.

For this to happen, you need to continue to call your css in the script `.theStyle` and you need to have your users assign an element to that style, such as `div.theStyle`, which has greater specificity and will override the former.

BTW: @Spudley is right about `!important`.

Comment: `style` will take precedence over `link[rel="stylesheet"]` for selectors with equivalent specificity.

Comment: True @zzzzBov. Edited to clarify.

Comment: I knew I could use jQuery to add stylesheets to the DOM; it hadn't occurred to me that I could solve the cascade problem by `.prepend`ing it before the other linked stylesheets. Good idea there (although I think you meant `prependTo` like zzzzBov said).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

Inline styles will always take precedence over styles in your stylesheet.

Using `!important` is the correct method for having your stylesheet styles take precedence over your inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

You could always have a conditional statement to see if the CSS has already been set, and if it has, don't set it again with jQuery.

Comment: I wonder why I never thought of that. Probably because adding a conditional for each and every property (border, margin, padding, color, background color, etc.) would be a bit overwhelming. Still, if it's the only way....

Comment: Instead of calling `.css` and doing the conditional statement every time you want to set the CSS using jQuery, just write a custom function that does both. Shouldn't really add too much extra work.

Comment: Wex: that's true. The only problem I can foresee is things like "border: 1px solid black" -- which is actually six different CSS properties condensed into one -- being passed as a parameter to the plugin. I'll have to give that some thought.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. I'd suggest an extra option in your plugin for turning the styles on or off and only add the css based on that option.

Comment: -1 for the suggestion, not a good way to go about it, although you're correct on `!important` not having an opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The way some plugins does it is supply a parameter that the developer can use to override the default class names. So that if they want to override your styles, they can supply maybe a prefix-parameter to make all classnames be prefix.yourdefaultclassname.

Comment: But that still wouldn't override the inline styles, would it?

Comment: I assumed the inline styles were generated by your plugin. And if so, stick to using classes instead you can still use !important, while allowing users to override your default classes.

Comment: You can easily have a plugin option that says "don't use inline styles", then if it's set to true you just add the class names and not the inline styles.